# char word[] vs char word[5]

Tags: c, arrays, string

I am struggling to find a reason for this, since the books I'm reviewing tell me to initialize a size for my array, yet, this compiles.

```
int main (void){

    char word_0[] = "Hola que tal\n";

    printf("%s", word_0); 

    char word_1[20] = "Hola que tal\n";

    printf("%s", word_1);

    return 0;
}
```

I know I'm "wasting" memory in word_1, since I'm asking more space (size = 20) than I need but what happens with word_0 (size = ?)?

Comment: Maybe I counted one more, but certainly not the `\n` as two characters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When an array is declared without any size specified but with an initializer, C chooses a size just large enough to accommodate all the elements specified by the initializer.  In the case of your

> ```
>     char word_0[] = "Hola que tal\n";
> ```

, that is 14 chars (which includes one for the string terminator).

Answer (score 2):

The compiler picks the size automatically.

Comment: Merely saying the size is picked automatically fails to specify what value is used for the size.

Comment: Fair enough. Do you know if the standard prescribes exactly the minimum size? I believe it does because I’ve seen `sizeof(word)/sizeof(word[0])` used as the length.

Comment: How the size is determined is specified by C 2018 6.7.9 14, which says “An array of character type may be initialized by a character string literal or UTF–8 string literal, optionally enclosed in braces. Successive bytes of the string literal (including the terminating null character if there is room or if the array is of unknown size) initialize the elements of the array.” and 22, which says “If an array of unknown size is initialized, its size is determined by the largest indexed element with an explicit initializer.”

Comment: Thus, the bytes of the string literal become the initializers for the array, and the array element initialized by the terminating null character is the largest indexed element, so that sets the size of the array: It is the length of the string, including the terminating null character.

Answer (score 0):

To combine @Ben and @JohnBollinger answers,

The 
`char_word[] = "Hola que tal\n"` 
statement indicates to the compiler that the size of the array will be initialized based on the string literal or `"Hola que tal\n"`.

So, in this case, the compiler would've said that the declaration of `char_word[]` is equivalent to `char_word[14]`.